# string comparison fails in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm using Alert() just to make sure I have a match between 'Login' and the innerHTML of an element on the page.

```
var statusElement = document.getElementById('logged-in-status');
var currentLoggedInStatus = statusElement.innerHTML;

    alert("innerHTML is: " + currentLoggedInStatus);
```

When the alert box pops up, it says:  **innerHTML is: Login**

```
    var stringComp = (currentLoggedInStatus == "Login");
    alert("stringComp is: " + stringComp);
```

When this 2nd alert box pops up, it says:  **stringComp is:  false**

So the code inside this 'if' statement ERRONEOUSLY executes.  I don't see how
the first alert() clearly says the innerHTML is 'Login' and yet the code inside the
'if' statement goes right ahead and executes.  I tried single-quotes around 'Login'
and it did not help.

```
    if(currentLoggedInStatus != "Login")
    {
       navBarLoginStatusTextElement.innerHTML = 'Login';
    }
```

To reiterate, the innerHTML = Login and when I compare innerHTML to Login
it says they're not the same!

Why is my javascript comparison above failing?

EDIT:  here is the block element and the php function that sets the value of 'Login':

```
<a id="logged-in-status" 
       href="http://localhost/myProj/justAfile.php"><?php echo getLoginStatusStr();?> </a>
```

and in a php block is the function:

```
 function getLoginStatusStr()
 {
      return 'Login';
 }
```

Comment: Please JSFiddle the code, or link to it if possible. I would possibly suggest that the innerHTML is actually 'Login ' rather than 'Login'... So change your debug alert to  alert("stringComp is: '" + currentLoggedInStatus + "'"); to verify this please.

Comment: What you get when you have this instead? `var stringComp = (currentLoggedInStatus.indexOf("Login") >= 0);`

Comment: Your link `#logged-in-status` seems to end with a whitespace, just as @AlanFoster suspected. Trim it before you compare it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Please JSFiddle the code, or link to it if possible. I would possibly
>   suggest that the innerHTML is actually 'Login ' rather than 'Login'...
>   So change your debug alert to  alert("stringComp is: '" +
>   currentLoggedInStatus + "'"); to verify this please.

Posted my original comment as an actual answer.

**Edit**: As i thought,

```
href="http://localhost/myProj/justAfile.php"><?php echo getLoginStatusStr();?> </a>
```

See the white space? Delete it so that it looks like

```
 href="http://localhost/myProj/justAfile.php"><?php echo getLoginStatusStr();?></a>
```

Comment: I added the block code and the inline php function that sets the text also in my original question above.  I'm thinking based on everyone's comments it is the lone space right before the closing </a>

Comment: @wantTheBest Yep, I changed my post before you commented to confirm this :)

Comment: Thanks Alan.  Been writing code since the 1980s.  I used to say "once you've learned a couple languages they're all very similar' and "I'm past the stage of spending lots of time chasing something that ends up being one bad character."  Dagnabbit.  I'm giving everyone who mentioned the whitespace an up-arrow and accepting this one.  Thanks all.

Answer (score 3):

As the others said, there is probably an extra white space in your HTML code. Try [trim](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/faster-trim-javascript)ing it:

```
function trim(str) {
  return str.replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');
}

var stringComp = (trim(currentLoggedInStatus) == "Login");
```

That said, I advise you **not** to check HTML code contents for your logic - you never know what browsers (or scripts) do to your code. Better use a dedicated status variable or something like that.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the advice there.  The challenge is that by the time the page processes my code above, the navigation bar html has already been sent by the server by way of a require_once "navBarTopOfEveryPage.php" -- by the time the code above executes the 'Login' element has already appeared and the above code changes the 'Login' after the fact.  Gotta be a better way. My navBar php file uses a session variable to keep track of the 'logged in status.'

Comment: Not sure if I understand what your `navBarTopOfEveryPage.php` exactly does, but perhaps it could write a `<script language="JavaScript">var logged_in=<?=$_SESSION["is_logged_in"]?"true":"false"?>;</script>` code snippet to replicate the status in the JavaScript world.

Comment: Good gosh I'm there, thanks for that tip Udo -- my approach is hugely inelegant and kludgey, I'm going to take your advice, that was a big help, thanks, it's been a long night on this, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You've probably got some extra whitespace in the original string, which is invisible in `alert()` but will cause the comparison to fail.

Answer (score 1):

```
String.prototype.trim = function() {
a = this.replace(/^\s+/, '');
return a.replace(/\s+$/, '');
};
```

and then `var currentLoggedInStatus = statusElement.innerHTML.trim();`

Answer (score 0):

I also think you have some extra white spaces in your string. The simplest way to check this using alert is to add length of the string to alert message. This way you can see which of the string contain the white space/s if any.

I found one more problem when I was dealing with similar problem. If your incoming string is null terminated then trim functions will not work. You can use slice function to get rid of null terminator.